# How to add class objects to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

```
class Objects:
   def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name

   def sayHi(self):
      print("Hi! My name is " + self.name)

myObjects = []
object1 = Objects("David")
```

How do i put object1 into the myObjects?
And if i did put object1 in, how do I call it's sayHi func?

Comment: `myObjects.append(object1)` and `myObjects[0].sayHi()`. ..these are very basic python questions. i suggest you take a course or read a book first.

Comment: duplicate was second google result for your question's title with "python" after it

Answer (score 3):

you can simply append the object to the list:

```
myObjects.append(object1)
```

Later you can access these by iterating over the list as follows:

```
for obj in myObjects:
    obj.sayHi()
```